# Visual studion 2013 (pro) Razor IntelliSense not working for dynamic objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, intellisense, umbraco7

I had some trouble with my visual studio 2013 professional edition last week which meant I had to reinstall the software. I have set everything back up and I have noticed that the IntelliSense is not working in my razor files for dynamic objects within an umbraco 7 project. I may be wrong but I could sware that this used to work prior to the reinstallation of VS.

Consider the following code in an umbraco razor view

```
    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    //gets the home page using doc type alias (root node)
    var siteRoot = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("homePage");
    //gets the about us page using doc type alias
    var portfolioPage = siteRoot.Descendant("portfolioPage");
    //gets the gallery page using doc type alias
    var galleryPage = siteRoot.Descendant("galleryPage");

    var imagesToDisplay = portfolioPage.HasValue("imageAmount") ? portfolioPage.GetPropertyValue<int>("imageAmount") : 2;
}

    <!-- .container -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="post-heading-center">
            <h2>@(portfolioPage.HasValue("heading") ? portfolioPage.GetPropertyValue("heading") : portfolioPage.Name)</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="#">All Work</a>
            <!--get gallery albums-->
            @foreach (var type in galleryPage.Children)
            {
                var galleryAlbum = Umbraco.Media(type.GetPropertyValue<int>("image"));

                if (galleryAlbum.ChildrenAsList.Count() != 0)
                {
                  <a href="#" data-filter=".class-@type.Id">@type.Name</a>
                }
            }
        </nav>
    </div>
```

when using visual studio IntelliSense i get no options and a message informing me that its a dynamic expression and it will be resolved at runtime. IntelliSense just seems non existent.

[image]

I have resharpher ultimate installed and when i go to resharper > options and switch to the resharper IntelliSense i get the members from object and what looks like members that i have used elsewhere but resharper is not quite sure.

[image]

I know that the ChildrenAsList member (which is what i need) is available to the dynamic galleryAlbum object but why doesnt my IntelliSense tell me this.

[image]

The other thing that i have noticed is that my IntelliSense constantly stops working regardless if its in vs or resharper mode which also makes me believe something is screwed with this install. To fix i either have to close the code file or the project itself. So with the above in mind i have the following questions

1. Is it standard behaviour for vs IntelliSense not to work with
   dynamic objects in umbraco razor views?
2. Why do base object members show when using resharper IntelliSense
   and not when using VS IntelliSense?
3. Why does all IntelliSense constantly stop working?

If anyone has any info on the above then i would be really greatful. I have attempted

1. to reset all user settings via the import and export wizzard
2. Checked 'Auto list members' & 'Parameter information' in statement
   completion in vs options

Had no luck.

I have also raised this with the umbraco community https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/80911-razor-visual-studio-intellisense-not-working-for-dynamic-objects

Comment: `dynamic` = no intellisense, that's normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic objects can be anything, they are resolved at runtime.

Instead of using `Umbraco.Media` try using `Umbraco.TypedMedia` to get a strongly typed model. That way you **can** use intellisense

Comment: Cheers mate, thats a useful tip :)

Comment: No problem! The same goes vor Umbraco.Content and Umbraco.Member by the way.